# Get an instance of a class in a running process

Tags: c#

Using C#, is there any way to hook into a running application (my own app) and get an instance of a class?  As it stands right now I'm doing this

```
// Find the IAutomation interface.
Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();

foreach (Type type in types)
{
    if (!type.IsAbstract && type.GetInterface("IAutomation") != null)
        automation = (IAutomation)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

This creates a new instance of the application each time.  I don't want a singleton application! I want to attach to an existing instance (if it exists) and pluck out IAutomation from there.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(VS.85).aspx), or make your existing instance a COM server, and use COM interop to the existing instance.

Maybe there are some debugging API's that you can use as well, but that I would not consider clean.

Answer (score 0):

If there's an existing instance of the IAutomation interface in the AppDomain there must be something pointing to it otherwise it would be garbage collected. So you will need to identify what is pointing to the instance and use it to get the instance. You should ask yourself questions such as: Who created the instance? It's probably this object that's holding the reference.